# Download AD user certificates using PBIS in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, active-directory

I am using PBIS([likewise-open](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LikewiseOpen)) tool to join to Active Directory domain from my ubuntu machine. **I would like to know if there is some command to download user certificates from AD using PBIS.**

I came across the binary **[adcert](http://linuxtoo.com/linux_certificate/Using_Centrify_adcert/518949/)** which is used with **centrify** which is a similiar software. However, **I want to get this done using PBIS**. If any one here have any experience with the same, please share your answers.